# need help sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the case of whether the date exists or a valid date: the text calculates the period between two dates per month and days and multiplies it by the amount of compensation in the number of person who benefit from it

Example: Number of person 2, compensation amount 4000 DZD, the period between 01/04/2020 to 2/18/2020 (1 month and 14 days)

```
(((4000 DZD * 14 days) / 30) + (4000 DZD * 1 month)) * 2 Number of people = 11733.33 DZD
```

problem in query

If the file has one compensation, it will calculate, and if the file has a set of compensation, an error is displayed

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when the subquery is used as an expression.

the question:
How can I show all the compensation and the corresponding accounts for each file separately so that if I change the file number for example "20/0003"
i use this code for sql query:

```
DECLARE @days int;
DECLARE @month int;
DECLARE @Total dec(18, 2);
IF (SELECT ISDATE(date_debut1)FROM Indemnite WHERE id_aff = '20/0002') = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @month = DATEDIFF(MONTH, date_debut1, date_fin1)
    FROM indemnite;
    SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, date_debut1, date_fin1), date_debut1), date_fin1)
    FROM indemnite
    WHERE id_aff = '20/0002';
    IF @days < 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @month = @month - 1
        FROM indemnite;
        SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, @month, date_debut1), date_fin1)
        FROM indemnite
        WHERE id_aff = '20/0002';
    END;
    SELECT @month = @month * 1 % 12;
    SELECT @Total = (((montant_dette1 * @days) / 30) + (montant_dette1 * @month)) * n_personne1
    FROM Indemnite
    WHERE id_aff = '20/0002';
END;
IF (SELECT ISDATE(date_debut1)FROM Indemnite WHERE id_aff = '20/0002') = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Total = (montant_dette1 * n_personne1)
    FROM Indemnite
    WHERE id_aff = '20/0002';
END;
SELECT Indemnite1,
       n_personne1,
       date_debut1,
       date_fin1,
       montant_dette1,
       @Total AS Total
FROM Indemnite
WHERE id_aff = '20/0002';
```

Comment: "select @month = DateDiff(month, date_debut1, date_fin1)  from indemnite "
Here we are getting multiple values but you assigned to scalar variable.For scalar variable we can assign only one result value.

Comment: how can i do it please

Comment: Try with Table Variable

Comment: I *really* suggest you start making good use white space and line breaks; it makes your code *far* more readable.

Comment: As for the error, it's telling you the problem. If there are multiple rows, what are you expecting to happen instead? What value should be used? Also, `ISDATE` is a terrible fucntion (just like `ISNUMERIC`). It's use here **strongly** suggests you're storing dates as a `varchar` (a big problem unto itself), but you "have" (you don't need to here, you should be correcting your design) to use `ISDATE` use `TRY_CONVERT` instead; it is far better is so many ways.

Comment: For example `ISDATE(20200713)` will return `1`, but `CONVERT(datetime, 20200713)` will error.

Comment: You need to look into `set`.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with something like this. There's really no reason to break all that out into so many steps. You can see that you can build up complicated expressions so that you don't need to deal with just one row at a time.

```
select

    datediff(month, date_debut1, date_fin1) -
        case when datepart(day, date_debut1) > datepart(day, date_fin1) then 1 else 0 end as whole_months,
    datepart(day, dateadd(day, -datepart(day, date_debut1) + 1, date_fin1)) - 1 as whole_days,
            
    montant_dette * n_personel * (
        datediff(month, date_debut1, date_fin1) -
            case when datepart(day, date_debut1) > datepart(day, date_fin1) then 1 else 0 end * montant_dette1 +
        (datepart(day, dateadd(day, -datepart(day, date_debut1) + 1, date_fin1)) - 1) / 30.0
    ) as total,

    montant_dette * n_personel * (
        case when isdate(date_debut1) = 1 then /* really not a great practice */
            datediff(month, date_debut1, date_fin1) -
                case when datepart(day, date_debut1) > datepart(day, date_fin1) then 1 else 0 end * montant_dette1 +
            (datepart(day, dateadd(day, -datepart(day, date_debut1) + 1, date_fin1)) - 1) / 30.0 else 1 end
    ) as total_with_date_check

from Indemnite;
```

I removed the whole `% 12` business as I don't see the relevance in limiting the calculation to a single year.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help. Work great. I don’t forget your favor to help, thanks

Comment: Sorry professor
The code performs an excess day count and There are some negative total values which are wrong
Can you correct  the code please?

Comment: @tahaayyoub You didn't elaborate on how you're counting days. Please supply some specific values and I can look into it. If debut is earlier than fin then you would obviously get negative values though.

Comment: @tahaayyoub I see one mistake that I made and I believe that's corrected. But I'm still not sure if you're counting the last day. I broke apart the day and month calculations separately so you could see where they fit into the larger expressions.

Comment: The code sent calculates the difference between two dates within the starting date and the correct calculation of the difference without the start date, that is, the difference only
Sorry, I need this code, please

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the phrase (+1) and the code is working fine
Account problem remains and is
Some dates are blank and in this case the calculation is as follows:
montant_dette1 * n_personne1